# $f^m = f^k$ Proofs

Tags: real-analysis, functions, discrete-mathematics, function-and-relation-composition, proof-explanation

$1$. Prove that for any  $f :J_n → J_n $, there exists a positive integer $m$ such that $f^m = f^k$ for some positive integer $k < m$.

$2.$ Let $f :J_n → J_n$ be a function, and let $m$ and $k$ be positive integers such that $f^m = f^k$
and $m > k$. Prove that the restriction of $f$ to $f^k(J_n)$ is a bijective function from $f^k(J_n)$ to $f^k(J_n)$

Note : $J_n$ represents the set consisting of the positive integers from $1$ to $n$. For  example $J_5=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.

For $1$, I know that $f^m = f^{m-k} \circ f^k$. But, I have no idea on how to proceed beyond that. Any help I can get is appreciated.

Comment: What is $Jn$? (Presumably it's some finite set?)

Comment: Yes , for example  $J 5$ would be the set {1,2,3,4,5} while $J 3$ would be the set {1,2,3}. To my understanding $J n$ is the set {1,2,...,n}

Comment: That's sort of what I figured - it'd be better to edit that directly into your question; it's not standard notation and it's helpful to the reader of the question.

Answer (score 2):

There are only finitely many functions from $J_n$ to itself.  Therefore, whenever the length of any list of such functions exceeds the total number of such functions, then two members of that list must be equal.  For example, there are $256$ functions from $\{1,2,3,4\}$ to itself, so two of the functions $f, f^2, f^3,\ldots,f^{257}$ must be equal to each other.

Comment: Ok, but I am still unsure how I would attempt to show that two members of the list will be equal. It seems obvious from your example, but how would I show this in a more general/abstract case?

Comment: This argument works if the domain and the codomain are both the same finite set, regardless of which finite set that is.  The same proposition in a more general setting could mean doing this with an infinite set, but in that case is is not true, as is seen by this example: the set is $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ and the function is $x\mapsto x+1$. I don't know what else besides an infinite set would qualify as "a more general/abstract case". ${}\qquad{}$